# Doubt in an step in a complex problem proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, proof-explanation, real-numbers, alternative-proof

The problem in question is this one:

> Let $z_1$,$z_2$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$; $\rvert{z_1}\rvert$= $\rvert{z_2}\rvert$ and $\alpha$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that:
> $\rvert \alpha z_1+z_2\rvert$=$\rvert z_1+\alpha z_2\rvert$

My approach was that since   $\rvert{z_1}\rvert$= $\rvert{z_2}\rvert$ then their coefficients must be the same,so I could just rearrange the coefficients to prove the statement but then I realized that is wrong because there is an infinite amount of real numbers that could satisfy both sides of the equality  $\rvert{z_1}\rvert$= $\rvert{z_2}\rvert$ so the coefficients need not to be the same. When I looked at the answer I could understand pretty much everything except for the penultimate step. Here is the given answer.

> \begin{align}  \rvert{z_1}\rvert= \rvert{z_2}\rvert=r;r \in (0,\infty); \rvert \alpha z_1+z_2\rvert=\rvert z_1+\alpha z_2\rvert \Rightarrow \rvert \alpha z_1+z_2\rvert^2=\rvert z_1+\alpha z_2\rvert^2 \Rightarrow   (\alpha z_1+z_2) (\overline{ \alpha z_1+z_2})= (z_1+\alpha z_2) (\overline{ z_1+\alpha z_2})\Rightarrow  (\alpha z_1+z_2) ( \alpha \overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2})=( z_1+\alpha z_2)( \overline{z_1}+\alpha \overline{z_2})\Rightarrow \alpha^2 z_1 \overline z_1 + \alpha z_1 \overline z_2+\alpha z_2 \overline z_1+z_2 \overline z_2= z_1\overline{z_1}+\alpha z_1 \overline{z_2}+\alpha z_2\overline{z_1}+\alpha^2z_2\overline{z_2}\Rightarrow \alpha^2 r^2+\alpha^2=\alpha^2 +  \alpha^2 r^2\end{align}

My question is how does the penultimate step is implied by the last, specifically regarding the squares.

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful for you to think about it in the opposite direction.

Comment: Wrong way to write the proof. 'Implies' should be 'implied by'.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, seems I was asking two things in the same post whether there was a second approach (seems not) and as for the step of the proof I didn't understand. I'm only asking the latter now.

Comment: but then why is there a standalone \alpha^2 in the final part? And can you please elaborate on why do those two terms cancel, that is why are they the same? Thanks. @MartinR

Comment: @Ruben: Just for fun I have added an alternative proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final expression in that proof is wrong ($\alpha^2 r^2 + \alpha^2$ should be $\alpha^2 r^2 + r^2$), also all implications are in the wrong direction. I would write it as follows:

For $|z_1| = |z_2| = r > 0$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 |\alpha z_1 + z_2|^2 &= (\alpha z_1 + z_2) \cdot \overline{(\alpha z_1 + z_2)} \\
&= (\alpha z_1 + z_2) \cdot (\alpha \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2}) \\
&= \alpha^2 z_1 \overline{z_1} + z_2 \overline{z_2} + \alpha(z_1 \overline{z_2} + z_2 \overline{z_1}) \\
&= \alpha^2 r^2 + r^2 + \alpha(z_1 \overline{z_2} + z_2 \overline{z_1}) \, .
\end{align}
$$
The same holds with $z_1$ and $z_2$ exchanged:
$$
| z_1 + \alpha z_2|^2 = \alpha^2 r^2 + r^2 + \alpha(z_2 \overline{z_1}+z_1 \overline{z_2}) \, .
$$
The right-hand sides of both equations are the same, it follows that
$$
|\alpha z_1 + z_2|^2  = | z_1 + \alpha z_2|^2 
\implies |\alpha z_1 + z_2|  = | z_1 + \alpha z_2|\, .
$$

---

*An alternative proof.* This idea is to rotate the configuration so that the rotated points $z_1', z_2'$ are symmetric with respect to the real axis.

Let $s$ be a square root of $\overline{z_2}/z_1$. Then $|s| = 1$ and
$$
 s z_1 = \frac{\overline{z_2}}{s} = \overline{s z_2}
$$
and therefore
$$
\begin{align}
 |\alpha z_1 + z_2| &= |\alpha s z_1 + s z_2| \\
&= |\overline{\alpha s z_1 + s z_2}| \\
&= |\alpha s z_2 + s z_1| \\
&= |\alpha z_2 + z_1| \, .
\end{align}
$$